# How to start developing a well architected Javascript Library?

Tags: javascript, open-source, libraries, github

I want to start developing an. open-source javascript library. I can see other open-source libraries are well structured. They have src, dist, test kind of folders, etc.

Which is making me very confused. My end goal is i want to develop a well structured and well documented JS library, but initially i need some hierarchy and recommended tools which most of open-source famous library developers are using, because definitely if i will have a good and well structured library then contributors will join in all future planning.

Also i want to develop my library in modules like small files of each functionality and have tools automatically generate build/dist folder for whoever wants to use library and src folder easy to understand my structure for contributors.

Please feel free to ask me anything if you don't understand what i mean.

Thank you

Comment: There is no suitable way. to answer this in this forum. You should take a look at other libraries that you admire. Pick a project structure and tools and get started. Then as you. work you can revise and refactor to reach a state the you are satisfied with. Showing your tools and interfaces to other developers is a great way. to learn whether they. make sense. But just. asking. us. to lay. it out won't help you. We don't know your library's requirements.

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: Why did people do negative vote to my question? :(

Answer (score 1):

In the "Javascript world", there isn't *one* broadly accepted standard for folders and project hierarchies. But there are tons of frameworks for different purposes, and several of them impose a specific folder layout.

So the best recommendation here I can give you here is: find a few other existing libs or frameworks of comparable size and / or purpose, pick one of which you think it's layout could work for your case and start with that. When your library grows, you will learn if the decision was fine, or you may have to change things over time, but that is ok, don't overthink it.